# Using a loop to iterate through dates for a Facebook get_insights

Tags: python, facebook, api, loops

I'm new to Python and am trying to establish an API connection to Facebook to pull advertising campaign data. I want to pull for 6-12 months at a time and the Facebook API doesnt seem to handle this - so I'm trying to write a script to pull the data I need one day at a time using a loop.

I'm trying with the below code, but this just pulls for one day only - the last day in range. Can someone please correct me where I'm going wrong?

```py
today = datetime.now().date()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

start_date = date(2020, 8, 10)
end_date = today
day_count = (end_date - start_date).days
day = timedelta(days=1)

date = start_date
for i in range(day_count):
    date += day

fields = [
    'campaign_name',
    'reach',
    'impressions',
    'frequency',
    'clicks',
    'spend', ]

params = {
    'level': 'campaign',
    'filtering': [],
    'breakdowns': [],
    'time_range': {'since': str(date),
                   'until': str(date)},
    'time_increment': '1',
    "limit": 1000}

results = my_account.get_insights(fields=fields,
                                  params=params)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the indentation, it looks like you're firstly doing the for loop and after it finished, you're calling the get_insights function. By doing so, the for loop will get your days from the start_date up until today and in the end, the results will only call get_insights for today.

A solution for this would be just to indent it properly so that results will be **inside** the for loop.

Another thing that is to be noticed is that you're putting results = ...get_insights(...) which of course will override the results in the for loop over and over again, at the end remaining with today's insights.

To solve this, you can make an empty list before the for-loop and append to it as you're getting the insights.

Here's how the code should look like:

```
   today = datetime.now().date()
   yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

   start_date = date(2020, 8, 10)
   end_date = today
   day_count = (end_date - start_date).days
   day = timedelta(days=1)

   date = start_date

   results = []
   for i in range(day_count):
      date += day
  
      fields = [
         'campaign_name',
         'reach',
         'impressions',
         'frequency',
         'clicks',
         'spend',]

      params = {
        'level': 'campaign',
        'filtering': [],
        'breakdowns': [],
        'time_range': {'since': str(date),
        'until': str(date)},
        'time_increment': '1',
        'limit': 1000}

      results.append(my_account.get_insights(fields=fields,
            params=params))
```

In the end, the results will be a list of the insights for all the days in the given range.

Comment: Thanks for this - the few small adjustments worked and got me exactly what I need